# How to do a search in the state (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am able to store a data array containing the login and pass objects. I created an input field in which I write what I want to find in the state. How can I filter the state and display only matching items?

Constructor

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { login: "login", pass: "pass" },
        { login: "login2", pass: "pass2" }
      ],
      login: "",
      pass: "",
      find: ""
    };
```

Adding and displaying data

```
add(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  show(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!this.state.login.length || !this.state.pass.length) {
      return;
    } else {
      const newUser = {
        login: this.state.login,
        pass: this.state.pass
      };

      this.setState(state => ({
        data: state.data.concat(newUser)
      }));
    }
  }
```

Search

```
 filterUsers(e) {
    let { data } = this.state;

    //console.log(this.temp.login);

    this.setState({
      find: e.currentTarget.value
    });
  }
```

Render

```
<input onInput={this.filterUsers.bind(this)} />
  <div>{this.state.find}</div>
    {this.state.data.map((val, index) => (
    <>
      <td>{val.login}</td>

      <td>{val.pass}</td>

      <br />
      <div />
    </>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

What property are you filtering on? Login?
I recommend creating a filtered data array in your state so you don't modify the original.

```
filterUsers(event)
{
  let filteredArray = this.state.data.filter((user) => 
  {
    user.login === event.currentTarget.value;
    //or if you want partial matches
    //user.login.includes(event.currentTarget.value)
  })
  this.setState({
    filteredList: filteredArray
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your state.data remained untouched you can filter out your search-term in the render method.

```
filterUsers(e) {
    this.setState({
        find: e.currentTarget.value
    });
}


<input onInput={this.filterUsers.bind(this)} />
<div>{this.state.find}</div>
{this.state.data.filter(x => x.login.includes(this.state.find)).map((val, index) => (
    <>
        <td>{val.login}</td>

        <td>{val.pass}</td>

        <br />
        <div />
    </>
))}
```